# EsOutputFormat connection error using spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am trying to integrate spark and ES (1.2.1) using elasticsearch-hadoop 2.0.0. I will use EsOutputFormat to write to ES the results obtained from my spark jobs. I run into a strange problem where the error message says that there is a connectivity error.

I put the logs in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/sallum/c21882bb99dd884e6517).

I am bit confused with this exception as I am sure I can connect to ES through the default port:

```
$ telnet localhost 9200
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I am running java version 1.7.0_55 and scala 2.10.2. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: What happens when you run  curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200' ? How about  curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' ?

Comment: It connects fine to elasticsearch using localhost/127.0.0.1:
$ curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200'
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Node01",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "6c95b759f9e7ef0f8e17f77d850da43ce8a4b364",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-06-03T15:02:52Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.8"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spark in local mode or cluster mode? if cluster mode, then the worker executors in the cluster wont be able to access localhost

try putting in the network ip which is accessible to all nodes in your cluster

Answer (score 0):

when defining your index in Elasticsearch did you change the its size  ?
 because by default is 1000 , maybe your data is larger than the index size so it can't load the data . Try to change the index size by changing the settings :          "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000( for example)